# Raster or Brick from nedf with lat lon = matrix

Tags: r

I have a netcdf file 3 dimensions, lat, lon, time :

- lat and long are matrix (nrow=263, ncol=512)
- time is vector of date
- the variable is precip observed at a given (lat, lon) and date

What I would like is a brick (nrow=263, ncol=512) with the values = precip , one layer per date . That's what I try :

```
test=brick("netcdf_filename.nc", varname="precip")
```

And that's what I get :

```
Error in .rasterObjectFromCDF(x, type = objecttype, band = band, ...)
:    cells are not equally spaced; you should extract values as points
```

I also try to specify the grid properties like this :

```
brick("netcdf_filename.nc",varname="precip",nrows=263, ncols=512,
ymn=min(lat),ymx=max(lat),xmn=min(long),xmx=max(long),
crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84")
```

but I get the same error. I'm not an expert in handling geographic data , is there a solution to get a brick with this kind of netcdf file ?

Comment: See the angstroms package for a way to go about this with raster, in short you want angstroms::romsdata() (read as brick without the coordinates), and angstroms::romscoords() (read the coords as 2-layer brick).  The quadmesh::mesh_plot function can take the brick and the coords to plot in the usual way. Details really matter though so YMMV.  Otherwise, the stars package has a new way to treat this as a curvilinear grid that should work via read_stars() or read_ncdf()